# Finding time when acceleration is not constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

First of all, I'm sorry if this is an ignorant question, but it is for a personal project and its been bothering me.

Let's say you want to accelerate in you car for some amount of time, then let off the gas and come to a stop under friction having traveled exactly 1 kilometer(or any given distance).

My question is, how can you calculate how much time to accelerate in order to come to a stop at a predetermined distance?
The best I can come up with is this equation(which is probably dead wrong), where $\Delta x$ is the total distance, $a$ is acceleration, $t$ is time to accelerate, $F$ is the force of friction, and $m$ is the mass. Trouble is, I can't figure out how to isolate $t$.

$$\Delta x =\frac{1}{2}at^2+at+\frac{1}{2}(F/m)(at/Fm)^2$$

Comment: In your car example, the acceleration is a function of time $a(t)$ and not some constant. You get speed, as a function of time by integrating between the right boundaries; $v(t)=\int a(t)dt$, Similarly displacement will be found from $x(t)=\int v(t)dt$. You either *define* $a(t)$ or it will follow from a Newtonian equation of motion $F_{net}=ma$.

Answer (score 1):

If you accelerate your car with constant acceleration AND we then assume that the friction decelerates the car with constant (negative) acceleration, then you simply consider each situation for itself:

$$x_{acc}=x_{0,acc}+v_{0,acc}t_{acc}+\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2$$
$$x_{dec}=x_{0,dec}+v_{0,dec}t_{dec}+\frac12a_{dec}t_{dec}^2=1\;\mathrm{km}$$

Of course the start position $x_{0,dec}$ for the deceleration part is where the acceleration part arrived $x_{0,dec}=x_{acc}$ so we'll put it together:

$$1\;\mathrm{km}=x_{acc}+v_{0,dec}t_{dec}+\frac12a_{dec}t_{dec}^2
=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2+v_{0,dec}t_{dec}+\frac12a_{dec}t_{dec}^2$$

We'll need an expression for the velocity at the beginning of the deceleration part $v_{0,dec}$, but that's easy by using another of the motion equations:
$$v_{0,dec}=v_{acc}=v_{0,acc}+a_{acc}t_{acc}=a_{acc}t_{acc}$$

$$1\;\mathrm{km}=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2+a_{acc}t_{acc}t_{dec}+\frac12a_{dec}t_{dec}^2$$

Times $t_{acc}$ and $t_{dec}$ are unknowns. Let's plug in another motion equation, that we have still not used, involving time:

$$v_{dec}=v_{0,dec}+a_{dec}t_{dec}=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad t_{dec}=-\frac{v_{0,dec}}{a_{dec}}=-\frac{a_{acc}t_{acc}}{a_{dec}}$$
$$1\;\mathrm{km}=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2+a_{acc}t_{acc}\left(-\frac{a_{acc}t_{acc}}{a_{dec}}\right)+\frac12 a_{dec}\left(-\frac{a_{acc}t_{acc}}{a_{dec}}\right)^2\\
=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2-\frac{(a_{acc}t_{acc})^2}{a_{dec}}+\frac12 \frac{(a_{acc}t_{acc})^2}{a_{dec}}\\
=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2-\frac12 \frac{(a_{acc}t_{acc})^2}{a_{dec}}$$

So far so good. Let's have a look at the accelerations. We assumed them to be constant. That also means a constant net force acting. For the friction $f$ during the deceleration part that will be:

$$\sum F_{dec}=f=ma_{dec}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a_{dec}=f/m$$
$$1\;\mathrm{km}=\frac12a_{acc}t_{acc}^2-\frac12 \frac mf (a_{acc}t_{acc})^2$$

which we can insert (if the friction $f$ is known, of course). For the acceleration part, the engine of the car controls the acceleration, and the acceleration might be what you know, so let's keep $a_{acc}$ in there. And so, if you know the acceleration caused by the car, you can now find the time it must use to accelerate. By adjusting the acceleration you can adjust the time. Put that result into one of the other equations we came through along the way, and you can find the time for deceleration also, and there you have the total time as the sum.

All this is under the assumption made in the very first line: **That the acceleration in both parts are CONSTANT**! If that is not the case, these equations of motion don't apply, and the integrals (as some comments have mentioned) are the way to go. But if it *is* the case, as you seem to point at in your question, then you have the four equations of motion for each part of the motion to juggle around.

Answer (score 0):

There are a continuum of answers.

For any velocity, there is a distance that the car will travel to get to zero velocity with a frictional force of f.

Let's say you pick halfway point (1/2 kilometer) as that distancee, there is a certain velocity v at the halfway point that the car will coast to a stop under the friction f when it reaches 1 kilometer.

Accelerate your car to reach v at 1/2 kilometer then take your foot off the gas. You can do this for any point in between, assuming you can accelerate the car that fast.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. One must just solve the equation of motion given the external force and invert back for $t$.

Comment: it depends how fast you want to accelerate your car

Comment: The acceleration is given in terms of the external force acting on the particle, solving the equation of motion, at any time $t$. Once so, one has to just solve the equation back for $t$.

Comment: the acceleration depends on how hard you press on the pedal. The acceleration from the friction is constant.

Comment: How one applies the force (pedal, friction or all the rest) is irrelevant; once you have the force, you have a solution $\textbf{r}(t)$ for the motion that one can solve back to find $t$ (which is the actual question asked).